# swift - can't change UIImage tintColor

Tags: swift, uiimage, core-graphics, cgcontext, cgcontextdrawimage

I have a pattern PNG image, with black dots on transparent background, and I need to change dot's color at custom colors, for example yellow

I'm trying to change tint color before drawing it, but image is still black on transparent

```
let templateImage = UIImage(named: "spray7")!.withTintColor(.yellow, renderingMode: .alwaysTemplate)
                                        
 let image = templateImage.cgImage
 context.draw(image!, in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 8, height: 8))
```

and `context` is a `CGContext`

Any adviсe will be helpful!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

correct way is to use

```
let templateImage = UIImage(named: "spray7")!.tinted(with: .yellow)
```

instead

Comment: How could this have worked? There is not a member/method "tinted" for type UIImage.